# Hard time to understand :after selector CSS

Tags: css

According to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp, the after selector includes something after each element. I understand that perfectly. But i found a css-only slider in the internet, this one: [link](http://joshnh.com/2012/08/14/making-a-pure-css-featured-image-slider/#step1) where this part of the code

```
.slider label:after {
    border-radius: 100%;
    bottom: -.2em;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 .2em #111,
                inset 0 2px 2px #000,
                0 1px 1px hsla(0,0%,100%,.25);
    content: '';
    left: -.2em;
    position: absolute;
    right: -.2em;
    top: -.2em;
}
```

Makes the selected picture color the radios-circle in white. Shouldn't it be inserted after each label inside .slider ? Why does it aplies only to the selected one ?

Comment: It is confusing, which is not helped by w3fools misinformation, but it actually appends a *pseudo*-element to the end of the element selected. e.g. `<div class="slider"><label>Something... <pseudo-element /></label></div>`.

Comment: It's kinda confusing really... I guess i got it, i just don't understand how does it applies to the selected one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse your understanding is right. But specific to the slider, it also has below CSS rules.

```css
.slider input:checked + label {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The above code works like: **If the input is checked, add the
background color to the sibling(+) element which is label**

Comment: I understand the position, alright. I just don't get it how that code change the color of the checked label/input.

Comment: Undertood. Thanks for the CSS-help !

Answer (score 1):

It *is* applied to each label, not just the selected one.

Open the demo page: http://codepen.io/joshnh/full/KwilB

Right click the slider and choose "Inspect element" and locate the `ul class="slider"` element.

Check the `label` under each `li` element and notice the `::after` DOM node that's been generated by this CSS rule.  It's present on all the labels.

Comment: If it's applied to each label, why does it appear only in the selected one ?

Comment: Because only the selected slide is visible, the other slides are positioned "off the screen", so to speak.